# Jasmine with helpers

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm new on Jasmine testing, I need to test a nodejs express application.
I do not find any documentation about jasmine helpers else that are called before all tests.

Just trying I found that adding

```
beforeAll(async()=>{
   ...
});
afterAll(async()=>{
   ...
});
```

into my /spec/helpers/myhelper.js these functions are executed after and before all code, but I did not find documentation about this behavior into a helper. Is it a standard behavior?

Is it possible to create my helper function into myhelper.js and call this function during the test? how?

my actual /spec/helpers/myhelper.js is :

```
let server = require("../../app");
console.log('server started before tests....');

function testMethod(){
    console.log("test helper called");
}
```

**How to call my test helper method from my tests?**

I'm using jasmine version 3.2.1

Comment: You should typically have a `describe` block containing the `beforeAll` or `afterAll` methods, then your runner should handle them automatically (ie karma or mocha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jasmine test cases are inside `describe` block.

- Each `describe` block has its own `beforeAll`, `afterAll`,
  `beforeEach`, `afterEach`.
- There can be `describe` inside another `describe` block.

Typically, I have one spec file which includes one `describe` block for one unit under test. The setup and teardown of test cases for this unit under test will be in those 4 functions of this `describe`.

As far as I know, if you want to separate your helper function to the new file, you can just import it normally and execute it in setup and teardown of target `describe`. But I have never done it since I never encounter any scenario that some classes have same setup or teardown processes.

But here's how you can achieve that:

Create server in helper function

```
function setupServer() {
  let server = require("../../app");
  console.log('server started before tests....');
  console.log("test helper called");
  return server;
}

module.exports = { setupServer };
```

In spec file:

```
const { setupServer } = require('/myhelper');

describe('some unit', () => {
    let server;
    beforeEach(() => {
        server = setupServer();
    });

    it('some test', () => {});
});
```

Or if you don't need return at all. It can be as short as:

```
beforeEach(setupServer);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `beforeEach(setupServer)` also encourages the use of `this` context instead of return value.

Comment: Yes, but setupServer cannot be executed multiple times from different tests. example: test1 starts, the server also starts litening on port 3000, then the test 2 stasts but the port 3000 is currently used from the previuos test and the test cannot be executed. then i'm looking for a common file where start the server before all spec files will be executed.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your question. 

In that case, I found this question quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615638/how-to-run-jasmine-beforeall-for-all-test-files).

If you purpose is to run test in an e2e style (API-wised), the above link should do. But if you just want to test this app as integration, I would recommend you to isolate test cases and avoid start the whole app. To test routes, I use [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) and add that particular route to the express Application which is freshly created per test case.